# MacBook Pro 2020 M1 Big Sur not accepting the right password

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, password, big-sur, apple-silicon

I am sure that I am typing the right password but my computer doesn't accept it.
Mac doesn't show forget reset your password. When opening in Recovery Mode it doesn't show the startup disk. And when choosing options and continue, it doesn't show **Forget All Password?** option, so I am not able to use my AppleID to reset the password.

The most frustrating thing about it is I just bought a new MacBook Pro today; it was working a few hours ago but not now.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the **Caps Lock** is not turned on?

Comment: My password is all numbers. But yes I checked it.

Comment: You might want to bring this by an apple store to get it looked at. If your startup disk isn't showing up, it might be good to get someone to take a look at it directly.

Comment: May be the keyboard layout changed : in some layouts numbers are accessed with shift and on some other without shift. I think command-space can change keyboard layout.